# Element visibility trigger stops triggering on products loaded via ajax

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, google-tag-manager

I've set up an "Element Visibility" trigger in GTM and it works correctly only on the products that are not loaded via AJAX. The trigger is bound to css selector: "[data-itemid]" (without quotes)

I tried to load the elements with AJAX and put it in the container with both .html(data) and .replaceWith($(data)) functions from JQuery.

```
function(data) {
    var $data = $(data);
    var $productList = $('.product-list-ajax-js').replaceWith($data);
}
```

When the elements load they simply don't trigger the Element Visibility trigger from GTM

Edit:
I should have also mentioned that the "Observe DOM changes" option in GTM is enabled and after the AJAX loads I use a history.pushState() function

Comment: Did you find a solution?  I'm having a similar problem and the only work-around I've been able to find is to clear the container first with e.g. `$('.product-list-ajax-js').html('')` then insert the new contents inside a `setTimeout` with a short delay - 500ms seems to work consistently.  Far from ideal obviously!

Comment: One other observation - if the number of elements of the type the element visibility trigger is watching for changes, the trigger seems to continue to work, so a work-around could be to insert a dummy element if the incoming data has the same number of elements as currently exist

Comment: Did you find a proper solution to this problem yet?